# Sub queries in Apache Hive

Tags: azure, hive, subquery

I have a table with following structure

```
col1   col2   col3   col4   category
300    200    100     20      1
200    100     30     300     2
400    100     100    70      1
100     30     200     100    1
```

Now i am trying to calculate for col1 what % of total rows have value <= 100, for col2 what % of total rows have value<=50 and so on and from category I only want to select category 1

so the resulting table should look like

```
col1(<=100)  col2(<=50)
x%             x%
```

I tried something like this but don't know how to write sub query for this

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS Total, COUNT(value1)* 100 /Total) AS col1(<=100) FROM table1 WHERE Category=1 GROUP BY value1 HAVING value1 <=100
```

Looks like I need multiple select queries, plz help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try using CASE statement as below:

"SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN col1 < 100 THEN 1 ELSE  0 END) / COUNT(col1) AS pct_col1,
        SUM(CASE WHEN col2 < 50 THEN 1 ELSE  0 END) / COUNT(col2) AS pct_col2
 FROM table1;"

Thanks
Arani